# SDL Cannot find -lSDL_main on Release build configuration

Tags: c++, sdl

I am using codeblocks as my IDE.

I have all the linker settings perfect,  I have all the SDL libraries in and when I build in Debug configuration everything works fine.

I should also mention I am compiling a dll with SDL and so there is no main function.

The problem arises when I try and compile into Release configuration. I keep getting the same error no matter what I do:

```
ld.exe  cannot find -lSDL_main.
```

Comment: If there is no `main` function, why do you need SDL_main?

Comment: I dont know, how do I remove it then?

Comment: Remove the `-lSDL_main` argument from your configuration.  I've never used CodeBlocks, but hopefully you can find out where that is.

Comment: Never Mind I removed and it all works fine again! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no `main` function, there's no need for you to be linking **SDL_main**.  Remove it from your build configuration.